# Using perform(afterDelay:) within a while loop gives me a logic error?

Tags: swift, loops, delay

I am making a timer program which uses a slider to set a timer value and then updates a digital clock display to show the corresponding numerical time remaining as image files.

I am trying to run a 1 second delay function within a while loop, and update the image files each second, essentially trying to create a timer which updates the variables used to determine which images are used in real time.

I am having difficulty assigning counting down correctly: the variables used to set the image files `h`, `min1` and `min2` are set to `0` after a 1 second delay. It seems that the while loop calls the delay function once, iterates until the condition is met without delaying the timer and then displays the final values.

I've tried different methods of timing a 1 second delay including using the `let timer = Timer.` approach and `DispatchQueue.main.` approach but they don't seem to work.

```
    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider)
    {
        self.x = Int(sender.value)
        // Note I omitted the rest of this code as it concerned setting images while changing slider value, and used local variables.
    }

    var x: Int = 60
    var h: Int = 1
    var min1: Int = 1
    var min2: Int = 7

    @objc func animate2 ()
    {
        checkLbl.text = String(h) + ("1")
        checkLbl2.text = String(min1) + ("1")
        checkLbl3.text = String(min2) + ("1")
        self.H2ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(h).png")!
        self.M1ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(min1).png")!
        self.M2ImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(min2).png")!
    }

    func animate ()
    {
        var timeLeft = x
        var seconds = 60
        while timeLeft >= 0
        {
            (h, _) = x.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 60)
            (min1, min2) = x.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 10)
            if min1 >= 6
            {
                min1 = min1 - 6
                if h == 2
                {
                    min1 = 0
                }
            }
            checkLbl.text = String(h)
            checkLbl2.text = String(min1)
            checkLbl3.text = String(min2)
            // checkLbl used to track the variables
            perform(#selector(animate2), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
            seconds = seconds - 1
            if seconds == 0
            {
                timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
                seconds = 60
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func watchPress(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        animate()
    }
```

To summarise: I expected the delay function to update `h`, `min1` and `min2` (and therefore update the `checkLbl` text) every second however these values go straight to `0`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `performSelector`, `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` and `Timer` all run code asynchronously after a certain time. This means that line B won't run one second after line A in this example:

```
checkLbl3.text = String(min2) // A
perform(#selector(animate2), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
seconds = seconds - 1 // B
```

Line B will run immediately after line A. And after one second, `animate2` will be called.

Therefore, you should not use a while loop. Instead, you should use a `Timer` like this:

```
Timer(timeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    if timeLeft == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    seconds -= 1
    if seconds == 0
    {
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1
        seconds = 60
    }
    // update the labels and image views
}
```

I also recommend you to only store the time left as a number of seconds. Remove your `h`, `min1`, `min2` and `seconds` variables. Only calculate them from the time left when you update the UI.